# Python (pandas) Query Data Frame from SQL Server database error

Tags: python, sql-server-2017, pypyodbc

I am trying query python data frame from a SQL Server database and I am getting an error. I think error is SQL syntax is too long?

But I don't know where it is wrong.

FUNCTION

```py
import dash 
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc 
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html 
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output 
import dash_table as dt 
import pandas as pd 
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash 
import pyodbc 
import dash_core_components as dcc

server = '' database = '' username = '' password = '' cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server +
                      ';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password) cursor = cnxn.cursor()


#sql syntax
query = """SELECT  inf_billnom.year  , inf_billnom.week  , inf_billnom.month  , Case inf_billnom.compno when '1' then '東方' when  '2' then '中遠' else  '物流' end  , Max(   inf_billnom.vslcode ) vslcode , Max(   inf_billnom.vslnm ) vslnm , Max(   inf_billnom.voyno ) voyno , Max(   inf_billnom.vslno ) vslno , Max(   inf_billnom.blno ) blno ,  Case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then '進口' when  'E' then '出口' else  '未區分' end  ,  inf_billnom.tax_regno  , Max(   inf_billnom.trade ) trade , Max(   inf_billnom.tradelane ) tradelane , Max(   tradelane.service ) service , Max(   inf_billnom.bound ) bound , Max(  inf_billnom.is_blready ) is_blready , Max(   inf_billnom.cargo_nature ) cargo_nature , Max(  inf_billnom.commodity + ( case when inf_billnom.commodity1 is null then ' ' else ' '  + inf_billnom.commodity1 end )  ) commodity , Max(   inf_billnom.traffic_mode ) traffic_mode , Max(   inf_billnom.ob_departure_date ) ob_departure_date , Max(   inf_billnom.ib_arrival_date ) ib_arrival_date , Max(   inf_billnom.sail_date ) sail_date , Max(   inf_billnom.segment ) segment ,  case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then inf_billnom.consignee else inf_billnom.shipper end  , Max(   inf_billnom.ccp ) ccp , Max(   inf_billnom.shipper_id ) shipper_id , Max(   inf_billnom.shipper ) shipper , Max(   inf_billnom.consignee_id ) consignee_id , Max(   inf_billnom.consignee ) consignee , Max(   inf_billnom.notify_id ) notify_id , Max(   inf_billnom.notify ) notify , Max(   inf_billnom.also_notify_id ) also_notify_id , Max(   inf_billnom.also_notify ) also_notify , Max(   inf_billnom.agree_num ) agree_num , Max(   inf_billnom.agree_type ) agree_type , Max(   inf_billnom.ctrl_reg ) ctrl_reg , Max(   inf_billnom.frm_city ) frm_city , Max(   inf_billnom.frm_country ) frm_country , Max(   inf_billnom.to_city ) to_city , Max(   inf_billnom.to_country ) to_country , Max(   inf_billnom.svccode_1st ) svccode_1st , Max(   inf_billnom.svccode_mother ) svccode_mother , Max(   inf_billnom.pol_mother ) pol_mother , Max(   inf_billnom.pod_mother ) pod_mother , Max(   inf_billnom.dir ) dir , Max(   inf_billnom.loadsvvd_1st ) loadsvvd_1st , Max(   inf_billnom.discsvvd_last ) discsvvd_last , Max(   inf_billnom.por ) por , Max(   inf_billnom.fnd ) fnd , Max(   inf_billnom.pol ) pol , Max(   inf_billnom.pod ) pod , Max(   inf_billnom.tport ) tport , Max( inf_billnom.frm_location ) frm_location , Max(   inf_billnom.to_location ) to_location , Max(   inf_billnom.por_region ) por_region , Max(   inf_billnom.fnd_region ) fnd_region , Max(   inf_billnom.terminal_1st ) terminal_1st , Max(   inf_billnom.termina_last ) termina_last , Max(   case when inf_billnom.nomcargos = 'Y' then '自攬貨' when inf_billnom.nomcargos = 'N' then '指定貨' else '' end  ) nomcargos , Max(   inf_billnom.department ) department , Max(  case when employee.cname is null then inf_billnom.sales else employee.cname end  ) sales , Max( inf_billnom.inside ) inside , sum(  1  ) blcnt , sum(  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end  ) size_20 , sum(  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 else 0 end  ) size_40 , sum(  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 else 0 end  ) size_45 , sum(   case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 else 0 end  ) cntrcnt , round (sum(  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end  ), 3)  teu , Max(   inf_billnom.pay_method ) pay_method , Max(   inf_billnom.shipperkind ) shipperkind , Max(   inf_billnom.isdg ) isdg , Max(  ' ' ) emptykey , Max(  ' ' ) emptykey1 , Max(  ' ' ) emptykey2 , Max(   inf_billnom.liner ) liner , inf_billnom.quarter  , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '01' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month01 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '02' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month02 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '03' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month03 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '04' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month04 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '05' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month05 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '06' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month06 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '07' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month07 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '08' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month08 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '09' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month09 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '10' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month10 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '11' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month11 , round (sum( case when inf_billnom.month = '12' then ( case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_20 else 0 end +  case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_40 * 2 else 0 end + case when 0= 0 then inf_billnom.size_45 * 2 else 0 end) else 0 end  ), 3)  month12 , Max(  view_fnd.value_new ) region FROM {​oj inf_billnom LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON inf_billnom.compno = employee.compno AND inf_billnom.sales
= employee.emp_id                                         LEFT OUTER JOIN tradelane ON inf_billnom.trade = tradelane.trade AND inf_billnom.tradelane = tradelane.tradelane AND inf_billnom.compno = tradelane.compno                                         LEFT OUTER JOIN view_fnd ON inf_billnom.compno = view_fnd.compno and ( case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then inf_billnom.fnd else inf_billnom.por end )  = view_fnd.value_old }​     wHERE 'TRUE' = 'TRUE'   AND  ( inf_billnom.compno ='1' or inf_billnom.compno = '2' or inf_billnom.compno = 'N' )  AND ( ( inf_billnom.ix_cd ='I'  and  inf_billnom.year + inf_billnom.month between '202001' and '202001'   ) or  (  inf_billnom.ix_cd ='E'  and  inf_billnom.year + inf_billnom.month between '202001' and '202001'  ) )  Group by  inf_billnom.year , inf_billnom.week , inf_billnom.month , inf_billnom.quarter ,  Case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then '進口' when  'E' then '出口' else  '未區分' end , Case inf_billnom.compno when '1' then '東方' when  '2' then '中遠' else  '物流' end ,  inf_billnom.tax_regno ,  case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then inf_billnom.consignee else inf_billnom.shipper end  Order by  inf_billnom.year , inf_billnom.week , inf_billnom.month , inf_billnom.quarter ,  Case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then '進口' when  'E' then '出口' else  '未區分' end , Case inf_billnom.compno when '1' then '東方' when  '2' then '中遠' else  '物流' end ,  inf_billnom.tax_regno ,  case inf_billnom.ix_cd when 'I' then inf_billnom.consignee else inf_billnom.shipper end;"""


df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

Error:

> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\kctadmin\Envs\django3_dash\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1725, in execute
> cur.execute(*args, **kwargs) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]語法錯誤或違反存取規則 (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\users\kctadmin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "c:\users\kctadmin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kctadmin  \Envs\django3_dash\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kctadmin\Envs\django3_dash\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 75, in inner_run
> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]語法錯誤或違反存取規則 (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Thanks